# Ubuntu 16.04 - No default sound device for laptop after unplugging headphones

Tags: 16.04, sound

I connected my Dell Inspiron with Ubuntu 16.04 installation to an external monitor earlier, I had headphones plugged in and the sound was working fine at this point.

I earlier removed the HDMI cable from the laptop and since then I have had no working sound through either the laptop or the headphones connected.

Through PulseAudio Volume Control, under Configuration, I see only HDMI output profiles, and no default built-in audio profile.

I see no output devices listed under 'Play Sound Through' on the Sound Settings interface.

Plugging the HDMI port back into the laptop gives me an option for HDMI / DisplayPort on the Sound Settings interface

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.
The following actions worked for me:

1. Update Pulseaudio:

   ```
   sudo apt install pulseaudio
   ```
2. Restart Pulseaudio:

   ```
   pulseaudio -k && pulseaudio -D
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling

- pulse audio
- pavucontrol
- alsa
- alsa-base

and then reboot. 
Or try

Step 1: In terminal remove pulse audio,alsa,alsa-base,pavucontrol one by one

"sudo apt purge pulseaudio "
 "sudo apt purge alsa"
 "sudo apt purge alsa-base"
"sudo apt purge pavucontrol"

and make sure to log everything what happened i.e which dependent programs got  removed too.

Step 2: Then issue "sudo apt autoremove" to remove any unwanted programs.Log these one too.

Step 3 : then reboot your system. "sudo reboot"

Step 4: Install the programs again.(one by one)
         1. alsa
         2. alsa-base
         3. pulseaudio
         4. pavucontrol

```
"sudo apt install alsa"
"sudo apt install alsa-base"
"sudo apt install pulseaudio"
"sudo apt install pavucontrol"
```

Make sure to log these one too to check which programs got installed.

Step 5: reboot your system and check wheter the audios are back or not

Anyways I had earlier fixed the issue myself and[my audio fix in linux mint](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=227487)